# Adding a custom column to SQL query

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a DB built like this:

```
NUM    VALUE    
 1      3.51
 2      hello
 1      3.487
 2      goodbye
 1      32.4
 2      foo
```

what I need to do to add another column in which all the values having num "2" will be in.

e.g.

```
NUM     VALUE     value2
 1       3.51      hello      
 1       3.487     goodbye
 1      32.4       foo
```

any idea how I can do this?
thanks!

Comment: Database?  And how to know what values are paired up?!

Comment: @marc_s: My formatting!  My beautiful formatting...

Comment: Is there some additional sequence field (a date or an ID) that will exactly define the order of those rows with `Num=1` and `Num=2` ?? E.g. how do I know that "3.51" and "hello" belong together??

Comment: @OMG Ponies: formatting, schmormatting ..... mine is just as nice :-9

Comment: yes, there is a date column which contains the same value for each pair(e.g. 3.51 & hello). and sorry about the wrong format.. my 1st question :)

Answer (score 3):

In this example I am using SQLite, where the table Source already has a built-in rowid.  Depending on the database you are using, you may need to add your own auto-incrementing integer column (i.e., integer primary key), but the idea is the same.

```
CREATE TABLE Source (num, value);
INSERT INTO Source (num, value) VALUES (1, 3.51);
INSERT INTO Source (num, value) VALUES (2, 'hello');
INSERT INTO Source (num, value) VALUES (1, 3.487);
INSERT INTO Source (num, value) VALUES (2, 'goodbye');
INSERT INTO Source (num, value) VALUES (1, 32.4);
INSERT INTO Source (num, value) VALUES (2, 'foo');

"1","3.51"
"2","hello"
"1","3.487"
"2","goodbye"
"1","32.4"
"2","foo"

SELECT a.num, a.value, b.value
FROM Source a
INNER JOIN Source b ON a.rowid = b.rowid - 1
WHERE a.num = 1 AND b.num = 2

"1","3.51","hello"
"1","3.487","goodbye"
"1","32.4","foo"
```